# How to plot an array of 0/1 using matplotlib

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib, matrix, colors

I'm given an input of 1/0 matrix. And i want to plot it to look like that:
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyhPE.png)

The thing is that i have to color all the zeros in blue. but when given a matrix of only ones it also turns into blue. is there a way to make the color "stick" with a specific number?

the code i've used:

```
cmap = ListedColormap(['b', 'g'])  
matrix=np.array(matrix,dtype=np.uint8) 
plt.imshow(matrix,cmap=cmap)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could specify the default number of entries in the colormap using the `ListedColormap` method as you thought, just set the optional argument `N = 2`. Also, define the minimum and maximum values for your data in the `imshow` method with `vmin` and `vmax`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
import numpy as np

# Random matrix

data_ones = np.random.randint(1, 2, size=(8, 8))
data_both = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(8, 8))

# Define colormap

cmapmine = ListedColormap(['b', 'w'], N=2)

# Plot matrix

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
ax1.imshow(data_ones, cmap=cmapmine, vmin=0, vmax=1)
ax1.set_title('Ones')
ax2.imshow(data_both, cmap=cmapmine, vmin=0, vmax=1)
ax2.set_title('Zeros and Ones')
plt.show()
```

Which plots:
[image]